# Process radio stream real time

Tags: c++, audio

I want to create a program in C++ that is able to process a radio stream (audio) in real-time that is broadcasted over the internet. However, I dont know how to get this audio stream in my program. Maybe it is possible to play the audio stream in a browser and capture the audiostream from the audiocard in my program or something?

The final goal is to process the stream and recognize a specific sound that I already recorded.

All tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) library.  It supports grabbing multimedia sources off the internet such as RTSP through the internal use of [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

For instance, you can use the `ffmpeg` command-line binary (this is a binary based on the ffmpeg C-libraries) to grab a real-time multimedia stream like so:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://some-server.youtube.com/some-media.3gp -acodec copy -vcodec copy filename.3gp
```